# C++ Exception re-throwing and elipsis

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch, throw

Let :

```
void foo( void )
{
    throw std::exception( "" );
}

void bar( void )
{
    try
    {
        foo():
    }
    catch( ... )
    {
        throw;
    }
}

void baz( void )
{
    try
    {
        bar();
    }
    catch( ... )
    {
    }
}
```

What does baz() catch ? An std::exception or something else ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It catches the same `std::exception` that was thrown by `foo`. (At least, it would, if it were possible to throw `std::exception` like that in the first place.) `throw;` with no operand rethrows the exception object that's currently being handled.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `baz` catches `std::exception` in this case.

But be careful when throwing `std::exception` because it should be used as a base class of exceptions. C++ Standard (Paragraph 18.8.1) specifies that `std::exception` only has a default constructor and a copy constructor, so you cannot put message into it.

Consider using `std::runtime_error` instead.

Comment: It was just for the example. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: `std::exception` is completely portable across standards-conforming implementations. There is no restriction to use as a base class.

Comment: @PeteBecker, `std::exception` is completely portable, but you cannot throw it as it is abstract on most platforms (with the exception of MSVC).

Comment: No, according to the C++ standard, 18.8.1 [exception], `std::exception` is **not** an abstract class. You may well be right that some implementations get this wrong; I haven't looked.

Comment: @PeteBecker, yes you're right, it's not an abstract class. But anyway you cannot `throw std::ecxeption( "message" )` because C++ Standard (Paragraph 18.8.1) specifies that `std::exception` only has a default constructor and a copy constructor.